# iOS recorded video for all web browser support

Tags: ios, iphone, html, video

In ios application, capturing video in mp4 format and uploading it to amazon server.

we are embedding this uploaded video url in html file using video tag.

The problem is, it wont play in firefox since is it doesn't support mp4 format .
in some forum and blogs I have seen that we need to provide multiple formats of video (mp4, ogg, webm etc) in html.
but uploading different file format videos to server is not a good solution.

Any solution for this to achieve, with once format from iOS device , and it need to support in at least chrome , firefox and safari browsers .

Comment: Hello, having a similar problem,how do you capture the video in mp4 using html5?

Comment: @mattias I havent tried after that , Check the below link and see if this would help you ,https://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-video-gallery/one-mp4-format-to-play-in-all-web-browsers-and-devices/

Answer (score 1):

If Chrome PC/Mac, Firefox PC/Mac, and Safari Mac/iOS are what you support, then you ***needed*** to provide 2 video sources and 2 audio sources:

## *HTML 5 Video*

> src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"
>   src="video.webm" type="video/webm" codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"

## *HTML 5 Audio*

> src="audio.m4a" type="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.5"
>   src="audio.ogg" type='audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"

I agree, it's ridiculous, fortunately Mozilla has given up on [boycotting patent encumbered media formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) and has enabled Firefox (v35) Mac to play MP4s. I just recently discovered that AAC (MP4 audio) is compatible with Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. So now life is much more simpler:

## *HTML 5 Media Nirvana*

> src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"
>   src="audio.m4a" type="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2"

The only browser that's left out is [Opera](http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/formats/), I can live with that.