# HTML5 Video Won't Play In Firefox

Tags: firefox, html5-video

I have converted my video to `.mp4` and `.webm` formats for use on the web. As from my understanding Firefox doesn't support `.mp4` but its does support `.webm`

This means having both should support all browsers.

I have the following HTML to display my video,

```
             <video width="100%" height="auto" controls>

                <source src="6-steps-to-becoming-an-elite-internet-marketer\_\video\mp4\part-0-t4ej1dbeuk.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="6-steps-to-becoming-an-elite-internet-marketer\_\video\webm\part-0-t4ej1dbeuk.webm" type="video/webm">

                Oppps! Your browser appears to not be able to play this video. Please update it!

            </video>
```

It works in Chrome, IE and Safari however not in Firefox.

I get the error message `"No Video with supported format and MME type found"`

I've added the following into my .htaccess to support all types.

```
# HTML5 video to work in all browsers
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

I've spent hours on this very issue but just having no luck.

Comment: If your paths are correct, this looks like it should work.  Try loading the page with the Firefox error console open - if you're getting a 404 when trying to load the webm, your path is wrong.

Comment: I checked this, I get a 404 error not found for both files. However in Chrome they are found and displayed absolutely no problem. So the paths are correct but it's saying there are not.

Comment: Are you running any firefox addons?  What hosting provider are you using?

Comment: No I'm not and currently using XAMPP local host server. I figured it out and posted my answer, thanks for your help! You helped me figure it all out with the idea of using Firefox error console!

Comment: Problem solved. I found answer in this stackoverflow post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656465/html5-video-not-playing-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

Firefox are very specific on the type of slashes you can use. I was using backwards slashes copied from a windows file path.

Soon as I changed the slashes to forward such as the following,

```
<source src="6-steps-to-becoming-an-elite-internet-marketer/_/video/mp4/part-0-t4ej1dbeuk.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

It worked! `.mp4` video works too, like perfect!

So it was never anything to do with the file or MME types. Hope this helps someone out there who finds themselves in the same shoes.

Comment: Just FYI, Firefox used to have a boycott on MP4 because of licensing issues, hence the neccessity of WEBM. Mozilla has caved in and now Firefox can indeed play MP4 like every sane browser should. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471476/ios-recorded-video-for-all-web-browser-support/30152918?s=1|1.9119#30152918